# Setup ShutdownHook and exit application

Tags: java, authentication, event-handling, system-shutdown, shutdown-hook

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // login event
    String event = "login";
    System.out.printf("Handling event: %s %s\n",event,getCurrentLogin());
    sendMessage(event, getCurrentLogin());

    // logout or shutdown event
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                String event = "logout";
                System.out.printf("Handling event: %s %s\n",event,getCurrentLogin());
                sendMessage(event, getCurrentLogin());
        }
    }));
 }
```

It's a very simple program for logging user's login and logout. The problem is that the program exits when reaches the end of function main().

Am I using to the shutdown event hook correctly?
I don't want to create a complex windows service, it must be a very simple application cause it will be used for remote connected windows sessions.

Do you have any suggesion for background waiting for the login termination ?

Answer (score 2):

The ShutdownHook is a thread that is executed when the JVM is exiting and the program is not doing anything after you execute the "sendMessage":

```
sendMessage(event, getCurrentLogin());
```

You should wait for a signal to exit, like a Ctrl+C on the console.
Just wait for a lock or Semaphore to avoid the program finalization, and that lock should be released when you need to finish it.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a latch to your example to try to make the example work. I unfortunately do not have an IDE to test, but this should be enough to give an idea.

EDIT : The example below would print both login and logout.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            // login event
            String event = "login";
            System.out.printf("Handling event: %s %s\n", event, getCurrentLogin());
            sendMessage(event, getCurrentLogin());
            final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

            // logout or shutdown event
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String event = "logout";
                    System.out.printf("Handling event: %s %s\n", event, getCurrentLogin());
                    sendMessage(event, getCurrentLogin());
                    latch.countDown();
                }
            }));
            latch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        private static void sendMessage(String event, Object currentLogin) {
        }

        private static Object getCurrentLogin() {
            return "X";
        }
    }
```

Comment: this won't compile because the latch isn't final. See my answer for the right way ;)

Comment: Corrected it, and didn't I give a disclaimer that this is just to give an idea and not a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to wait infinitely until the OS stops your program, is that right? If so, you need to have at least one daemon thread running:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    //...
    final Object o = new Object();
    synchronized(o) {
        while(true) {
            o.wait();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure thet the OS will kill the JVM gently enough, and that the shutdown hook will execute, though. Test it.

Answer (score 0):

The shutdown hook is called when the application finalize. So if you want to let you application run forever you need to implement something as:

```
while (true) {
    //Your logic here
}
```

If you want to write a daemon or scheduler maybe you need to use some framework as Quartz http://quartz-scheduler.org

If you want to implement a daemon you can use a Service Wrapper like http://yajsw.sourceforge.net or http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers here but I still see some missing information.

Your code registers a shutdown hook in `main` and then main reaches the end and returns.  The shutdown hooks are called when the last non-daemon thread exits.  I suspect that main is the only non-daemon thread so when `main` exits the hook is immediately called.

If you don't want your program to exit immediately then `main` will have to loop and wait for some sort of signal.  From the context of your question, I guess it should be listening for some sort of response from `sendMessage` call?  If you want to wait for control-c then I like @JB Nizet's answer for this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ...
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(...);
    // wait until control-c is called
    final Object o = new Object();
    synchronized(o) {
        while(true) {
            o.wait();
        }
    }
}
```

You want to start waiting *after* you register your shutdown hook so your shudown code gets executed.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one approach using a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to keep the main-thread waiting:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // login event
    String event = "login";
    System.out.printf("Handling event: %s %s\n",event,getCurrentLogin());
    sendMessage(event, getCurrentLogin());

    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    // logout or shutdown event
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                String event = "logout";
                System.out.printf("Handling event: %s %s\n",event,getCurrentLogin());
                sendMessage(event, getCurrentLogin());
                latch.countDown();
        }
    }));

    latch.await();
 }
```

Comment: I don't see the handling for InterruptedException?